# Why this code is not working in VS2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I want to use array of SQl Parameters.When i searched over net I got very usefule data at below 
link.[sqlParameters Array in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070932/sqlparameters-array-in-vb-net).VS2005 shows syntax error near NEW.

Code is as below

```
Dim parameters() As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter() _
    {
      New SqlParameter("@first_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) With { .Value = "john"},
      New SqlParameter("@last_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) With { .Value = "doe"},
      New SqlParameter("@age", SqlDbType.Int) With { .Value = 18},
      New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int) With { .Value = 123}
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual error, and which `new` does it complain about?

Comment: Expression expected error at first '{'.Then each NEW word has Syntax Error.When I used same in VS2010,it works fine

Comment: I edited code to as '        Dim parameters() As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter() _
                                           {New SqlParameter("@first_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) With {.Value = "john"}}' still I am getting error as **} expected.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses [object initializers which where introduced in VB.Net 9.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vb9overview_topic4) (Visual Studio 2008); hence you can't use them in VB.Net 8.0 (Visual Studio 2005).

You have to do it the verbose way, e.g.:

```
Dim parameters(3) As SqlParameter

Dim p As SqlParameter
p = New SqlParameter("@first_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
p.Value = "john"
parmaters(0) = p

p = New SqlParameter("@last_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
p.Value = "doe"
parmaters(1) = p

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your link.I thought there is syntax level issue